# How to resolve datatype length difference errors while using unpivot in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

I am running below SQL statements in SQL Server which is causing issues due to difference in length of the column types (name=nvarchar(100), address=nvarchar(250)).

```
select distinct  
    Id, Label, [Value]
from
    (select distinct 
         coalesce([Value], 'unknown') as Id,
         coalesce([Value], 'unknown') + ':' + I as label,
         coalesce([Value], 'unknown') as [Value]
     from 
         [dummyDB].[test].[test]
     unpivot
         ([Value] for I in (name, address)) as dataTable
    ) as t
```

Error:

> Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
> The type of column "address" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

How to get this resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `APPLY` and `VALUES` to unpivot the data instead, you don't get this error. Using these tools is more versatile that the `UNPIVOT` operator anyway, so I personally prefer them:

```sql
SELECT T.ID,
       V.Label,
       V.[Value]
FROM dbo.Test T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Name',T.Name),
                        ('Address',T.Address))V(Label,Value);
```

If you have non string-type columns, you'll need to explicitly convert them (possibly with a style code):

```sql
SELECT T.ID,
       V.Label,
       V.[Value]
FROM dbo.Test T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Name',T.Name),
                        ('Address',T.Address),
                        ('SomeDate',CONVERT(nvarchar(10),T.SomeDate,112)),
                        ('SomeInt',CONVERT(nvarchar(5),T.SomeInt)))V(Label,Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu. Just curious, if we have to do it anyway using unpivot, how would we do that ?

Comment: You would have to explicitly convert the values to all be the exact same data type, @Naxi .